# Does in iOS 7.0 AVSpeechSynthesizer have US male voice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, avspeechsynthesizer

**Solution** : It doesnot have `US male voice`

---

I have used `AVSpeechSynthesizer` `framework` for `iOS7.0`

```
AVSpeechUtterance *utt = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Hello"]; 
if (isMale) //flag for male or female voice selected
{
    // need US male voice as en-US is providing only US female voice
    utt.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-GB"]; //UK male voice 
}
else
{
    utt.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"]; //US female voice
}
```

I need to use `US male voice` instead of `male UK voice`.

Comment: So what is the issue, Can you brief you problem?

Comment: I need to use US male voice instead of male UK voice.

Comment: I think `en-GB` should be taken as a male voice with English Language instead of taking it as a UK Male voice. I am not sure but that's what we can think of as Apple hasn't provided us with any other male US voice.

Comment: Any updates on the question? did iOS 8 add the en-US male(Alex) voice yet? I could see it from settings, but it requires to download separately. Maybe just use us-Au after downloaded voice package

Answer (score 2):

iOS still doesn't provide US male voice. 
You can find all BCP-47 code of available voices

```
for (AVSpeechSynthesisVoice *voice in [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice speechVoices]) {
NSLog(@"%@", voice.language);
}
```

Comment: solution is provided in questions only